# Rails i18n and EasyTranslate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using a locale :cn which is not recognized by EasyTranslate. I am trying to create the `if` in the controller such as:

```
def index
    @events = Events.all
    if I18n.locale == :cn
      @locale = ":zh-CN"
    else
      @locale = I18n.locale
    end
  end
```

so that I can use the following in my view:

```
<%= check_box_tag "by_cities[]", city %> <%= EasyTranslate.translate(city, :to => @locale, :key => @key)  %>
```

BUt I get an `EasyTranslate:EasyTranslateException in Event#index Invalid Value`
How can i get EasyTranslate to take the new locale just for this method please?
Thank you 
Et

```
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
easy_translate (0.5.1) lib/easy_translate/request.rb:47:in `perform_raw'
easy_translate (0.5.1) lib/easy_translate/translation.rb:34:in `request_translations'
easy_translate (0.5.1) lib/easy_translate/threadable.rb:24:in `block in threaded_process'
easy_translate (0.5.1) lib/easy_translate/threadable.rb:24:in `map'
easy_translate (0.5.1) lib/easy_translate/threadable.rb:24:in `threaded_process'
easy_translate (0.5.1) lib/easy_translate/translation.rb:20:in `translate'
app/views/events/index.html.erb:21:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_events_index_html_erb___49110152348777287_70221206769120'
app/views/events/index.html.erb:19:in `each'
app/views/events/index.html.erb:19:in `block in _app_views_events_index_html_erb___49110152348777287_70221206769120'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:39:in `block in capture'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:203:in `with_output_buffer'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:39:in `capture'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:70:in `form_tag'
app/views/events/index.html.erb:15:in `_app_views_events_index_html_erb___49110152348777287_70221206769120'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:157:in `block in render'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:352:in `instrument_render_template'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:155:in `render'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:42:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:41:in `instrument'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:51:in `block in render_template'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:59:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:50:in `render_template'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:103:in `_render_template'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:52:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:141:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:24:in `render'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:36:in `render'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/Users/etienne/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
searchkick (3.1.2) lib/searchkick/logging.rb:214:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:29:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
wicked_pdf (1.1.0) lib/wicked_pdf/pdf_helper.rb:42:in `render_with_wicked_pdf'
wicked_pdf (1.1.0) lib/wicked_pdf/pdf_helper.rb:27:in `render'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:33:in `default_render'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `block in send_action'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `tap'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:186:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:131:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:252:in `process_action'
searchkick (3.1.2) lib/searchkick/logging.rb:209:in `process_action'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:124:in `process'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:189:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:253:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:31:in `serve'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `each'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `serve'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:844:in `call'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/migration.rb:556:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
rollbar (2.18.0) lib/rollbar/middleware/rails/rollbar.rb:24:in `block in call'
rollbar (2.18.0) lib/rollbar.rb:146:in `scoped'
rollbar (2.18.0) lib/rollbar/middleware/rails/rollbar.rb:22:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59:in `call'
rollbar (2.18.0) lib/rollbar/middleware/rails/show_exceptions.rb:22:in `call_with_rollbar'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:22:in `block in call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `catch'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
request_store (1.4.1) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:19:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.1.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/server.rb:658:in `handle_request'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/server.rb:332:in `block in run'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:133:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: Could you post full stacktrace for this error?

Comment: Hello, I just added stacktrace.

Comment: Error is cause by translate API responsing with error. Hard to tell why, maybe because of an invalid language code? 
https://github.com/seejohnrun/easy_translate/blob/master/lib/easy_translate/request.rb#L45-L48

Comment: There must be a way to pass the locale to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple actually : 
In the **controller** :

```
   if I18n.locale == :cn
      @locale ="zh-CN"
      else
      @locale  = (":"+ (I18n.locale).to_s)
    end
```

In the **view**:

```
<%= check_box_tag "by_cities[]", city %> <%= EasyTranslate.translate(city, :to => @locale, :key => @key)  %>
```